# How to maintain the row order of an xlsx spreadsheet when converting to nested json with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've created a script which successfully imports an excel spreadsheet (xlsx) into a dataframe and then exports that dataframe to a nested json file, with python/pandas. The problem is, in the output json file, the rows are in a completely random order, compared to the xlsx spreadsheet. The script looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

df = pd.read_excel('xlsx-file-url-goes-here', dtype={
            "a" : str,
            "b" : str,
            "c" : float,
            "d" : float,
            })

results = []

for (a, b), bag in df.groupby(["a", "b"]):
    contents_df = bag.drop(["a", "b"], axis=1)
    e = [OrderedDict(row) for i,row in contents_df.iterrows()]
    results.append(OrderedDict([("a", a),("b", b),("e", e)]))

output = json.dumps(results, indent=2)
with open('results.json', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(json.dumps(results))
```

As I say, this does perfectly output a nested json file, grouped by columns a and b. The problem is that the row order is not correct. The rows are in a random order as far as I can tell.

How can I modify this code to maintain the original row sorting in the excel spreadsheet? The rows in that were in ascending order based on one of the grouping columns, like a or b. Thanks!

EDIT

The dataframe, which does maintain the correct order, looks like this:

```
  a               b               c               d
0 Other String    Other String    100             200
1 Other String    Other String    300             400
2 String          String          100             200
3 String          String          300             400
```

The expected json output would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "a" : "Other String",
    "b" : "Other String",
    "e" : [
            {
              "c" : 100,
              "d" : 200,
            },
            {
              "c" : 300,
              "d" : 400,
            }
          ]
   },
  {
    "a" : "String",
    "b" : "String",
    "e" : [
            {
              "c" : 100,
              "d" : 200,
            },
            {
              "c" : 300,
              "d" : 400,
            }
          ]
   }

]
```

This is arbitrary content, but that's what it looks like when being processed by my script. Only problem is, even though in the excel spreadsheet, the 'Other String' would come before 'String', that doesn't happen in the actual json file.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe (for example, using `df.head().to_dict()` and your expected output.

Comment: Thanks @not_speshal, I have edited the question to add examples of the dataframe and json output. I hope that helps. The real dataframe (and xlsx) has significantly more rows and columns, so it was easier to give arbitrary values as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result = (df.groupby(["a","b"])
            .apply(lambda x: x.drop(["a", "b"], axis=1)
                              .to_dict(orient="records"))
            .rename("e")
            .reset_index()
            .to_json(orient="records"))

#write to file:
with open('results.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(result)

>>> result
'[
  {
    "a": "Other String",
    "b": "Other String",
    "e": [
      {
        "c": 100,
        "d": 200
      },
      {
        "c": 300,
        "d": 400
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": "String",
    "b": "String",
    "e": [
      {
        "c": 100,
        "d": 200
      },
      {
        "c": 300,
        "d": 400
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that still outputs the same incorrect order. In addition, there are many redundant backslashes in the json file now. Is there a way round that?

Comment: This is what I get with the example you posted. Correct order and no backslashes. Not sure what's different about your actual data but you would probably need to provide it to be able to check.

Comment: I see. I think my issue could be how I have exported it to a json file. How would you export that to create a json file? Your output does of course look like I would want.

Comment: Edited to include that code.

Comment: I appreciate that, thanks for adding the output method. That does remove all of the backslashes. The problem is, using your exact method, it still comes out in the wrong order. I'll keep digging and see what I can find.